# How can I list the running processes by Dask?

Tags: python, dask

I am getting started with dask. For my own understanding (and that of my colleagues to whom I want to demonstrate dask), I want to construct a basic dataframe, do a basic operation and compare the execution time with a pandas-only implementation. This is my very simple attempt:

```
import dask
import dask.multiprocessing
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
import time

dask.set_options(get=dask.multiprocessing.get)

start = time.time()

df = dd.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(data={'a': list(range(10))}), npartitions=4)
df['a'].apply(lambda x: time.sleep(2))

end = time.time()

print(f'time elapsed: {end - start}')
```

I am using the multiprocessing scheduler because I expected to see the processes appear in a `ps aux | grep python` call in a separate shell. However, I don't see them. Is there - for demonstration purposes - a way to list all the processes that dask is using?

For the record, I do see an improvement in elapsed time. The pandas implementation (not shown here) takes 20 seconds while the dask version takes 4 seconds. However, given the fact that I have used 4 partitions, I would've expected it to take 5.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the multiprocessing scheduler then Dask creates and destroys a `multiprocessing.Pool` on every call to `compute`.

For demonstrations I typically use the [distributed scheduler on a single machine](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/setup/single-distributed.html), which includes a nice dashboard with pages that show the processes, activity, and such.

```
$ pip install dask[complete] bokeh
or
$ conda install dask bokeh
```

Then

```
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client()

# navigate to http://localhost:8787/status
```

Comment: Thanks. I still don't see much changing when I run the code I posted in my question but maybe using `time.sleep()` is not a good approach.